# need help for change attribute of models on view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i need to change attribute of my models on views but this my code dosent work
view:

```
class TaskRequest(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsBenefactor,]
    def get(self ,request, task_id):
        obj = Task.objects.get(id=task_id)
        if not obj:
            raise Http404("not found")
        if obj.state==obj.TaskStatus.PENDING:
            data={
                'detail': 'This task is not pending.'
            }
            return Response(data , status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            obj.assign_to_benefactor(self , obj.assigned_benefactor)
            obj.save()

            data={
                'detail': 'Request sent.'
            }
            return Response(data , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

my code of view get object  If not available return 404 error if available and state equal to PENDING return some data otherwise change state to Waiting and assigned to benefactor user
but this my code doesnt work what can i do ?
and my models :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    class TaskStatus(models.TextChoices):
        PENDING = 'P', 'Pending'
        WAITING = 'W', 'Waiting'
        ASSIGNED = 'A', 'Assigned'
        DONE = 'D', 'Done'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        default=TaskStatus.PENDING,
        choices=TaskStatus.choices,
    )
    charity = models.ForeignKey(Charity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    assigned_benefactor = models.ForeignKey(
        Benefactor,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    age_limit_from = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    age_limit_to = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender_limit = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=User.Gender.choices,
        default=User.Gender.UNSET,
    )
    def assign_to_benefactor(self, benefactor):
        self.state = Task.TaskStatus.WAITING
        self.assigned_benefactor = benefactor
        self.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this lines of code:

```
obj.assign_to_benefactor(self , obj.assigned_benefactor)
obj.save()
```

To:

```
obj.assign_to_benefactor(obj.assigned_benefactor)
```

1. You don't need to explicitly pass `self` because it is automatically added as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods). Also, take note that `self` within `Task` should be a `Task` instance/object, so whatever you are trying to do with `obj.assign_to_benefactor(self,...` within `TaskRequest` is incorrect because the `self` there is a `TaskRequest` instance/object, not a `Task` instance object.
2. Calling `obj.save()` is already redundant because you are already saving the instance from within `Task.assign_to_benefactor`
3. For your consideration, I'm not sure if you have other cases that calls `Task.assign_to_benefactor` but take note that with the pasted code in the question, you are just assigning the same `assigned_benefactor` to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
task.assign_to_benefactor(request.user.benefactor)
```